# In R: Join two dataframes based on a time period condition

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr

Being new to R, I am trying to merge two data frames by considering a ***time period*** condition.

```
df1 <- data.frame("first_event" = c("4f7d", "a10a", "e79b"), "second_event" = c("9346","a839", "d939"), "device_serial" = c("123","123","123") , "start_timestamp" = c("2019-12-06 11:47:0", "2019-09-06 11:47:0", "2019-09-05 10:00:00"),"end_timestamp" = c("2020-01-10 12:59:38", "2019-11-22 12:06:28", "2019-11-22 12:06:28"), "exp_id" = NA)

df2 <- data.frame("device_serial" =  c("123","123") , exp_id= c("a","b") ,    start_timestamp = c("2019-12-03 07:12:20", "2019-09-04 10:00:00") ,       end_timestamp = c("2020-01-17 00:05:10", NULL)     ,    current_event_id = c("1", "2")   ,current_event_timestamp= c("2020-01-17 00:05:09", "2020-01-17 00:05:09"))
```

This is little bit difficult to explain, I will do my best to present the problem.

Basically, I am monitoring some **expeditions** (`df2`) and I want to know which **events** (`df1`) are related to a certain expedition (Have a look at the **`exp_id`**
 in the `df1`, I want to fill this column).

Note that each expedition is created by a device, and evidently, each event is generated by a device. You may say this is feasible by **joining the two tables based on the id of a device**. However, the problem is that each device can be associated with multiple expeditions. 
So, the objective is to see during a certain time period the device was related to which expedition so we can match events with that expedition. If you look at the third row of `df1` you will see the difficulty I have for the time period condition. Because considering the duration in which the third row was recorded, we can not relate it to the expedition `a`.

Here comes the other problem. Sometimes the expeditions are not finished, so, we have to consider the **last seen event timestamp** (which is the current_event_timestamp in `df2`).

```
>df1

first_event   second_event      device_serial      start_timestamp        end_timestamp           exp_id
  4f7d            9346             123           2019-12-06 11:47:0     2020-01-10 12:59:38         NA
  a10a            a839             123             2019-09-06 11:47:0    2019-11-22 12:06:28        NA
  e79b            d939             123           "2019-09-05 10:00:00"    "2019-11-22 12:06:28")    NA

>df2
device_serial   exp_id    start_timestamp        end_timestamp         current_event_id   current_event_timestamp

   123             a      2019-12-03 07:12:20    2020-01-17 00:05:10        1             2020-01-17 00:05:09

   123             b      2019-09-04 10:00:00    NULL                       2             2019-11-23 12:06:28
```

The result that I am looking for is a table like this `df3`:

```
>df3
first_event   second_event      device_serial      start_timestamp        end_timestamp           exp_id
  4f7d            9346             123           2019-12-06 11:47:0     2020-01-10 12:59:38         a
  a10a            a839             123             2019-09-06 11:47:0    2019-11-22 12:06:28        b
 e79b            d939             123           "2019-09-05 10:00:00"    "2019-11-22 12:06:28")     b
```

Thanks for reading this question and helping me to solve it.

Comment: `dplyr` does not do joins on time ranges but `data.table` does, either using `foverlaps` or inequality merges. To do it elegantly (and with reasonable performance), I recommend using `data.table`, at least for this merging.

Comment: BTW, your `df2$end_timestamp` should not have `NULL` in it. The consequence is that since that vector is now length 1 (null removed), `data.frame` happily carries it down the column for all (2) rows, which is almost certainly not what you intend. Do you instead mean to use `NA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions, if I understand you correctly.

First, your data, with a few edits:

1. Per @r2evans comment, I'm assuming the `NULL` was meant to be
   `NA_real`
2. "current_event_timestamp" from `df2` in the first block of
   code does not match what you typed out in the second block; I used
   the datetime from the second block, as it led to the answer you were
   looking for

```
df1 <- data.frame("first_event" = c("4f7d", "a10a", "e79b"), 
                  "second_event" = c("9346","a839", "d939"), 
                  "device_serial" = c("123","123","123") , 
                  "start_timestamp" = c("2019-12-06 11:47:0", "2019-09-06 11:47:0", "2019-09-05 10:00:00"),
                  "end_timestamp" = c("2020-01-10 12:59:38", "2019-11-22 12:06:28", "2019-11-22 12:06:28"), 
                  "exp_id" = NA)

df2 <- data.frame("device_serial" =  c("123","123") , 
                  exp_id= c("a","b") ,    
                  start_timestamp = c("2019-12-03 07:12:20", "2019-09-04 10:00:00") ,       
                  end_timestamp = c("2020-01-17 00:05:10", NA_real_)     ,   
                  current_event_id = c("1", "2")   ,
                  current_event_timestamp= c("2020-01-17 00:05:09", "2019-11-23 12:06:28"))
```

Now, to tidy the data a bit.

Two main points:

1. It seems like the start_timestamp and end_timestamp columns in `df1` refer to starts 
   and ends of **events**, whereas those *same column names* in `df2` refer to starts and 
   ends of **expeditions**. If so, it's good practice to assign these variables names 
   that reflect the fact that the data they contain differ. In this case, this 
   distinction is important when joining the two tables.
2. At least in your example `df`s, note that all columns were read in as factors 
   initially. Variables are usually much easier to work with if they're stored as the 
   type of data they represent, and this is especially true for datetime data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
```

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  as_tibble(df1) %>% # convert to tibble; prints data type of each column
  select(-exp_id, evnt_start = start_timestamp, evnt_end = end_timestamp) %>% # removing exp_id (not necessary, & messes up join) & changing names of time cols.
  mutate(evnt_start = as_datetime(evnt_start), # converting time columns to datetime type
         evnt_end = as_datetime(evnt_end))
df1
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  first_event second_event device_serial evnt_start          evnt_end           
  <fct>       <fct>        <fct>         <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 4f7d        9346         123           2019-12-06 11:47:00 2020-01-10 12:59:38
2 a10a        a839         123           2019-09-06 11:47:00 2019-11-22 12:06:28
3 e79b        d939         123           2019-09-05 10:00:00 2019-11-22 12:06:28
```

```r
df2 <-  df2 %>% 
  as_tibble(df2) %>% # convert to tibble
  rename(exp_start = start_timestamp, exp_end = end_timestamp) %>% # changing names of time cols
  mutate_at(.vars=c("exp_start", "exp_end", "current_event_timestamp"), ~as_datetime(.)) # converting time cols from factor into datetime type

df2
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  device_serial exp_id exp_start           exp_end             current_event_id current_event_timestamp
  <fct>         <fct>  <dttm>              <dttm>              <fct>            <dttm>                 
1 123           a      2019-12-03 07:12:20 2020-01-17 00:05:10 1                2020-01-17 00:05:09    
2 123           b      2019-09-04 10:00:00 NA                  2                2019-11-23 12:06:28
```

Now, to try for a solution using `dplyr::left_join` and `dplyr::filter`:

```r
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(exp_end_or_current = if_else(is.na(exp_end), current_event_timestamp, exp_end)) %>% #creating a new col with either exp_end OR, if NA, then current timestamp
  left_join(df1, ., by = ("device_serial")) %>%  #join df2 to df1 by serial #
  filter(evnt_start > exp_start & evnt_end < exp_end_or_current) %>%  #filter, keeping only records where EVENT start & end times are between expedition start & end times 
  select(-c(exp_end, current_event_id, current_event_timestamp))
df3
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  first_event second_event device_serial evnt_start          evnt_end            exp_id exp_start           exp_end_or_current 
  <fct>       <fct>        <fct>         <dttm>              <dttm>              <fct>  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 4f7d        9346         123           2019-12-06 11:47:00 2020-01-10 12:59:38 a      2019-12-03 07:12:20 2020-01-17 00:05:10
2 a10a        a839         123           2019-09-06 11:47:00 2019-11-22 12:06:28 b      2019-09-04 10:00:00 2019-11-23 12:06:28
3 e79b        d939         123           2019-09-05 10:00:00 2019-11-22 12:06:28 b      2019-09-04 10:00:00 2019-11-23 12:06:28
```

Comment: Such an elegant way of solving my problem which was not really well written. Thank you :)

Comment: @Soren, happy to help! Managing & wrangling (& explaining!) datetime data can be a pain.